# Wifi won't turn on after rooting

Tags: wi-fi, root-access

I have an Epson Moverio BT-200 Wearable glasses with Android 4.0.4 and kernel "3.0.21-00003-OMAP-Android+". I rooted the glasses, tried every method without success until I found KingRoot, which succeed in rooting.

After that, the wifi toggle on Settings won't enable. Sometimes is gray (without enabling me to tap it), and sometimes is clickable but when i tap it to turn it on it gets off again and the screen remains saying "Turning on Wi-Fi" forever.

I did not do anything else after rooting. What can be the cause? I tried factory resetting the phone via Settings > Backup, and it did not solve the issue (I also still have root after factory resetting).

I have read that flashing the original ROM could fix it, the problem is that Epson does not offer the ROM image anywhere.

Thank you.