# Cannot turn on WiFi - says "Turning on WiFi" and returns to OFF state

Tags: wi-fi

Since today I am not able to turn on the WiFi on my phone. When I try to turn it on it says
*Turning on Wi-Fi* , but nothing happens and it just returns to OFF state.

I would highly appreciate a solution for this problem.

Comment: Are there any other wireless connections affected? What device, OS, etc. are you using?

Comment: Same problem is mentioned here: [Wifi won't turn on after rooting](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/120391). There, OP suspects rooting caused it.

Comment: If it's a Samsung device, see this qeustion: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/201327/wi-fi-and-bluetooth-doesnt-turn-on-samsung-galaxy-a5-2016-a510fd

Answer (score 0):

Try turning `Airplane Mode` off (if it's on).

[image]